# use as3 swf inside as2 project

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript-2

I need to load as3 swf file into an as2 swf file, but as I can see in [adobe live doc](http://bit.ly/L7MeBT)  I can't do it.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Thanks

Comment: as3-based container to former main swf and loaded as3? You can catch the bugs on as2-as3 communication, though.

Comment: Thanks I will try to make as3 swf Warper and see how things are moving.

Comment: Of course, as3 swf still cannot be loaded into as2 one, but maybe you can load it into as3 wrapper and make them communicate via LocalConnection, if need be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your link:

> - SWF files written in ActionScript 1.0 or 2.0 cannot load SWF files written in ActionScript 3.0.

Unfortunately there's no magical solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

AS3 swf cannot be load in as2 projects.There will be a compatibility problem occurs.